# Is there any difference between Taskmgr.exe and LaunchTM.exe?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, task-manager, win32

Is there any difference between `Taskmgr.exe` and `LaunchTM.exe` in Windows?
Both of these System32 executables seem to just open the Task Manager.
If there is no difference then why have two different System32 executables that do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, both executables do the same thing which is to open the Task Manager. A minor difference is that when opening the Task Manager via `CTRL + ALT + DEL`, `LaunchTM.exe` launches `Taskmgr.exe` as a child process.

The end result when running either executable from the command line is the same.

Comment: Thanks, so `LaunchTM.exe` essentially calls `Taskmgr.exe` and they needed two different executables, one for `CTRL + ALT + DEL` and one for the application? Do you know why it was not possible to have a single executable for both jobs?

Comment: @Vasilis I didn't look very far into why that is but perhaps there's a reason that the software engineers and/or developers designed it that way.